# Python select specific column values from enumeration list based on column index list

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below code: i am reading a file, fetching header row, looking for specific header columns and storing their indices. Then i iterate through the rest of the rows and want the value of only those indices.

```
    import csv       
def csvReader(csvFileName):
    counter = 10
    keyMap = []
    header = ["Test1","Test2"]
    with open(csvFileName,'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,skipinitialspace=True)
        Firstline = True
        print(reader)
        for row in reader:
            if counter > 0 and Firstline == True:
                print(list(enumerate(row)))
                indexes =[i for i, j in enumerate(row) if j in header]
                print(indexes)
                Firstline=False
                counter = counter - 1
            elif counter > 0:
                a = dict(zip(header, map((lambda str: row[i] for i in indexes) ,row)))
                print(a)
                print('test')
                counter = counter - 1
        return keyMap   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    csvReader("C:/Test.csv")
```

Comment: There's a lot of weird things going on in your code. You are using list comprehensions, but never capturing the lists! So in effect, they do absolutely nothing. You also call `.append` with no arguments... Which should throw an error. I dont really understand your description of what you are trying to do, because it is a little vague, but it *sounds* like it could be relatively straightforward. Why don't you try to give example input and output?

Comment: In addition, the `counter` is not defined. and why would one want to subtract from a counter!

Comment: Are you simply trying to extract specific columns from a CSV?

Comment: I pasted the full code snippet, yes i am trying to extract specific columns from csv.

Comment: This is the line i am trying to fix so that: i get only specific column values.  a = dict(zip(header, map((lambda str: row[i] for i in indexes) ,row)))

Answer (score 0):

Folks- thanks for your response. I just fixed it. by changing to below:

```
a = dict(zip(header, map(str, (row[i] for i in indexes))))
```

But any better solutions, please share them.

Comment: Since you're already using a comprehension, you don't need `map()` i.e. `(str(row[i]) for i in indexes)` is sufficient

Comment: Your entire approach is very much over-engineered if you are just trying to select particular columns from a csv. Assuming you know the column names ahead of time, you simply could do `reader = csv.DictReader(f)` Then somthing like `data = [(r['Test1'],r['Test2']) for r in reader]` Assuming you want your fields in a tuple. If you wanted a `list` of `dict`s, something like `data = [{f:r[f] for f in header} for r in reader]`

Comment: Thanks pylanf and juanpa; I will try them out..!